# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'NativeVibrationSpec' for React Native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a problem with a React Native project.

Newly created project with `npx react-native init ProjectName`, installed `pods` on `iOS` and trying to run the project it throws this next error: **Cannot find protocol declaration for 'NativeVibrationSpec** in Xcode.

Node version: 14.18.1

Xcode version: 13.0 (13A233)

Simulator to run: iPhone 13 with iOS 15.0

Is there any resolve?

[image]

Comment: You may try this workaround: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32432#issue-1029195328

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading react-native to 0.66.3 fixed this issue for me.
Don't forget to install pods again.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. Was previously on 0.66.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

in my case issue was with the pod file:

```
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
```

and replace it with:

```
post_install do |installer|
   react_native_post_install(installer)
end
```

run pod install and it will work

Answer (score 1):

As commented by chengsam the issue is described in [this react-native's issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32432#issue-1029195328). GNU coreutils does not executes cp in the same way as native MacOS does, therefore the quickest solution is to remove coreutils or modify this file to make it work for either GNU or MacOS interpreter.
**node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.sh**

Change this line:

`cp -R "$TEMP_OUTPUT_DIR/" "$RCT_SCRIPT_OUTPUT_DIR" || exit 1`

To this:

`cp -R "$TEMP_OUTPUT_DIR/." "$RCT_SCRIPT_OUTPUT_DIR" || exit 1`

It is just an extra dot.

By the comments, I suspect that this has been resolved in newer react-native version however my project still need this version. I think that the chip has nothing to do here since I see reports of M1 but I have an intel one.

For more details to the [react-native's issue discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32432#issue-1029195328)

Answer (score 0):

For me I was able to solve by clearing node modules and pods.

1. rm -rf `node_modules`
2. rm -rf `yarn.lock`
3. `yarn`
4. `cd ios && pod deintegrate`
5. `pod install`