# React Native project - Cannot find protocol declaration for 'NativeVibrationSpec' while running in XCode 14.3

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, stack-overflow

I am facing this error "Cannot find protocol declaration for 'NativeVibrationSpec'" while running react-native project in XCode.
React native version: 0.72.4
Node Version: 18.12.1
XCode Version: 14.3

I tried:

1. Delete derived data
2. Build clean
3. Remove and add node_modules
4. Upgraded packaged
5. All solutions in: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32404
6. All solutions in: [Cannot find protocol declaration for 'NativeVibrationSpec' for React Native iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69671844/cannot-find-protocol-declaration-for-nativevibrationspec-for-react-native-ios)
7. All solutions in: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32432#issue-1029195328

I was expecting application to run.